# How to check an iCheck on the second page

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, icheck

I have the following code:

```
$("#add-new-size-grp").click( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url:"ajax-get-sizes.php",
        success: function(result){
            $("#sizegrp-table").html(result);
            var sizegrpSizesTable = $('#tbl-sizegrp-sizes').DataTable();
            //iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
              checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
              radioClass: 'iradio_polaris'
            });

            $("#modalNewSizeGrp").modal();
        }
    });
});
```

Which, in a nutshell, retrieves a chunk of data and from that forms a jQuery [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net). This is then returned and shoved into a DIV in the calling page.

The section which starts `$('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({` uses the [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) plugin to format the checkboxes which are the first column of the table.

This works perfectly for the first page of data. However, when the user moves to another page, or changes the page length, the newly displayed checkboxes do not have the formatting applied.

I have looked at using the `page` event to apply the formatting, but can't get it to work properly. Code I have tried is as follows:

```
$('#tbl-sizegrp-sizes').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    var dtable = $('#tbl-sizegrp-sizes').DataTable();
    var info = dtable.page.info();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
      radioClass: 'iradio_polaris'
    });

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

As requested, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4x0u18a/1/) demonstrating the problem. Notice the styled checkboxes on page 1, then switch to any other page.

Comment: Why don't you add FIDDLE focusing the problem ?

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694633/example-of-page-event-in-datatables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CAUSE

jQuery DataTables removes non-visible elements from DOM. That is why when you run `iCheck()` it only affects first page elements.

#### SOLUTION

Use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to define a function that will be called when table is drawn.

```js
var sizegrpSizesTable = $('#tbl-sizegrp-sizes').DataTable({
   'drawCallback': function(settings){
      //iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
         checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
         radioClass: 'iradio_polaris'
      });
   }
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4x0u18a/7/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.

Comment: there seems to be a bug with the fiddle navigation after one click

Comment: look again, click on nav button 2, then try clicking on any nav button

Comment: upon second glance, i also found that the checkboxes are no longer check-able when you click on another nav button

Comment: @indubitablee, it works for me in every modern browser, try to use other browser and see.

Comment: im currently using the most updated version of chrome. perhaps you forgot to update your jsFiddle link?  right now it points to: https://jsfiddle.net/m4x0u18a/4/. i'm not trying to sink your ship, im only asking cause i actually want to know if there's a way to apply the styles within the dataTable plug in

Comment: @indubitablee, you're right, it didn't work in Chrome, very strange. I have corrected my answer and will investigate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Gyro - perfect again. Many thanks. Was just playing with the same callback but you saved me time again.

Comment: @SiStone, corrected code should work in Chrome as well.